# filter numeric values from text in a list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list List(Hello, World, 23, Century, 4, Best) and I want to separate numeric values 23, 4 using Scala. I need a way to filter numeric from text items in the list using Scala. Please help

Comment: What are `Hello`, `World`, `Century`, and `Best`? Please, post code that actually compiles. Yours does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
list.collect {
  case i: Number => i
}
//returns: List[Number] = List(23, 4)
```

Thanks to @armnotstrong for pointing out that match type should be `java.lang.Number` rather than `Int`

Comment: well, the match type should be `Number` instead of `Int` as the op described :D

Answer (score 1):

```
val lst = List("Hello", "World", 23, "Century", 4, "Best")


val filteredList = lst.filter{{
  case num:Number => true
  case _ => false

}}

filteredList
```

Check [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mUOwpIXgSmeDspwCx7LEOQ) out

Comment: Thanks thats great! but lets say i have this list as List(Hello, World, 23, Century, 4, Best) called lst and I want to do something like: for (s <- lst) if s.isDigit print(s)

Comment: @MSharma you could do that by appending a `.foreach(print)` to the `filteredList` [like this](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/JVTLEGXLOT)